# How can I split words in a long string according to a list of values to create a new data frame in R?

Tags: r

I have the following string value: `"Y AFGHANISTAN Y ALBANIA A ALGERIA Y ANDORRA A ANGOLA Y ANTIGUA AND BARBUDA Y ARGENTINA Y ARMENIA Y AUSTRALIA A AUSTRIA Y AZERBAIJAN Y BAHAMAS Y BAHRAIN Y BANGLADESH Y BARBADOS Y BELARUS Y BELGIUM Y BELIZE Y BENIN Y BHUTAN"`

And I have a list of countries:

```
[1] "AFGHANISTAN"                              
  [2] "ALBANIA"                                  
  [3] "ALGERIA"                                  
  [4] "ANDORRA"                                  
  [5] "ANGOLA"                                   
  [6] "ANTIGUA AND BARBUDA"                      
  [7] "ARGENTINA"                                
  [8] "ARMENIA"                                  
  [9] "AUSTRALIA"                                
 [10] "AUSTRIA"                                  
 [11] "AZERBAIJAN"                               
 [12] "BAHAMAS"                                  
 [13] "BAHRAIN"                                  
 [14] "BANGLADESH"                               
 [15] "BARBADOS"                                 
 [16] "BELARUS"                                  
 [17] "BELGIUM"                                  
 [18] "BELIZE"                                   
 [19] "BENIN"                                    
 [20] "BHUTAN"
```

I would like to split the string at each of the values in the country list, so that my resulting data frame looks like so:

```
Vote Country
Y    Afghanistan
Y    Albania
A    Algeria
Y    ANDORRA 
A    ANGOLA 
Y    ANTIGUA AND BARBUDA 
Y    ARGENTINA 
Y    ARMENIA 
Y    AUSTRALIA 
A    AUSTRIA 
Y    AZERBAIJAN 
Y    BAHAMAS 
Y    BAHRAIN 
Y    BANGLADESH 
Y    BARBADOS 
Y    BELARUS 
Y    BELGIUM 
Y    BELIZE 
Y    BENIN 
Y    BHUTAN
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Is the name of every country in the string always followed by an "A" or a "Y"? That is, are there only two possible voting choices?

Comment: Sorry, I meant: ... preceded by an "A" or a "Y".

Answer (score 2):

You can split the string on either "Y" or "A" and create a 2-column dataframe from it.

```
data.frame(matrix(trimws(strsplit(string, "(?=\\bY\\b|\\bA\\b)", perl = TRUE)[[1]]),
           ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE))

#   X1                  X2
#1   Y         AFGHANISTAN
#2   Y             ALBANIA
#3   A             ALGERIA
#4   Y             ANDORRA
#5   A              ANGOLA
#6   Y ANTIGUA AND BARBUDA
#7   Y           ARGENTINA
#8   Y             ARMENIA
#9   Y           AUSTRALIA
#10  A             AUSTRIA
#11  Y          AZERBAIJAN
#12  Y             BAHAMAS
#13  Y             BAHRAIN
#14  Y          BANGLADESH
#15  Y            BARBADOS
#16  Y             BELARUS
#17  Y             BELGIUM
#18  Y              BELIZE
#19  Y               BENIN
#20  Y              BHUTAN
```

**data**

```
string <- "Y AFGHANISTAN Y ALBANIA A ALGERIA Y ANDORRA A ANGOLA Y ANTIGUA AND BARBUDA Y ARGENTINA Y ARMENIA Y AUSTRALIA A AUSTRIA Y AZERBAIJAN Y BAHAMAS Y BAHRAIN Y BANGLADESH Y BARBADOS Y BELARUS Y BELGIUM Y BELIZE Y BENIN Y BHUTAN"
```

Comment: What if the string contains a country that's _not in the list provided_? I'm probably being overly fussy, but the OP did say: " ...according to a list of values... ". Can you filter out any country ( or junk word ) that's not in that list? Maybe just add a _join at the end. And what if there is no A or Y after the country?

Comment: Yes, if we are interested only in the countries in the list we can join them. If there is no "A" or "Y" separating the country then I think Ben's answer is the way to go.

Comment: Hi all - thank you so much for the help. Unfortunately, there are some countries that voted N, and some that did not participate, which means there is no letter preceding their name. I should have clarified that in my post, but instead I kept the country list short and non-representative.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to use the list of countries, you could create a search string from it, and then split the string at those country names.

**Edit**: Additional modifications made based on comment.

First, the parentheses are escaped in the list of countries. For example: BOLIVIA (PLURINATIONAL STATE OF).

In addition, splits only occur at whole words (with space afterwards), so that DOMINICA is not pulled from DOMINICAN REPUBLIC.

There may need to be other (or better) regex modifications depending on the list you have. I hope this is helpful.

```
library(stringr)
library(stringi)

esc_countries <- stri_replace_all_fixed(countries, pattern = c("(", ")"), replacement = c("\\(", "\\)"), vectorize_all = FALSE)
searchStr <- paste0(esc_countries, collapse = "(\\s)|")
result <- as.data.frame(str_split_fixed(trimws(unlist(strsplit(string, paste0("(?<=",searchStr,")"), perl = T))), " ", 2))
colnames(result) <- c("Vote", "Country")
```

**Output**

```
   Vote                          Country
1     Y                      AFGHANISTAN
2     Y                          ALBANIA
3     A                          ALGERIA
4     Y                          ANDORRA
5     A                           ANGOLA
6     Y              ANTIGUA AND BARBUDA
7     Y                        ARGENTINA
8     Y                          ARMENIA
9     Y                        AUSTRALIA
10    A                          AUSTRIA
11    Y                       AZERBAIJAN
12    Y                          BAHAMAS
13    Y                          BAHRAIN
14    Y                       BANGLADESH
15    Y                         BARBADOS
16    Y                          BELARUS
17    Y                          BELGIUM
18    Y                           BELIZE
19    Y                            BENIN
20    Y                           BHUTAN
21    Y                            CONGO
22    Y BOLIVIA (PLURINATIONAL STATE OF)
23    Y                         DOMINICA
24    Y               DOMINICAN REPUBLIC
25    Y                         ZANZIBAR
```

**Data**

```
(from @Ronak Shah)

string <- "Y AFGHANISTAN Y ALBANIA A ALGERIA Y ANDORRA A ANGOLA Y ANTIGUA AND BARBUDA Y ARGENTINA Y ARMENIA Y AUSTRALIA A AUSTRIA Y AZERBAIJAN Y BAHAMAS Y BAHRAIN Y BANGLADESH Y BARBADOS Y BELARUS Y BELGIUM Y BELIZE Y BENIN Y BHUTAN Y CONGO Y BOLIVIA (PLURINATIONAL STATE OF) Y DOMINICA Y DOMINICAN REPUBLIC Y ZANZIBAR"

countries <- c(
  "AFGHANISTAN",                              
  "ALBANIA",                                  
  "ALGERIA",                                  
  "ANDORRA",                                  
  "ANGOLA",                                   
  "ANTIGUA AND BARBUDA",                      
  "ARGENTINA",                                
  "ARMENIA",                                  
  "AUSTRALIA",                                
  "AUSTRIA",                                  
  "AZERBAIJAN",                               
  "BAHAMAS",                                  
  "BAHRAIN",                                  
  "BANGLADESH",                               
  "BARBADOS",                                 
  "BELARUS",                                  
  "BELGIUM",                                  
  "BELIZE",                                   
  "BENIN",                                    
  "BHUTAN",
  "CONGO",
  "BOLIVIA (PLURINATIONAL STATE OF)",
  "DOMINICA",
  "DOMINICAN REPUBLIC",
  "ZANZIBAR")
```

Comment: This helps tremendously. I only have two smaller issues now. The first is with countries that have parentheticals, such as BOLIVIA (PLURINATIONAL STATE OF). The function you provided me does not split after those parenthetical countries. Is there a workaround for this? The second is with the countries DOMINICA and DOMINICAN REPUBLIC. This function splits after Dominica, but then cuts DOMINCAN REPUBLIC after DOMINICA is identified, leaving me with DOMINICA \n N REPUBLIC. Does that make sense? I would love some suggestions as to how I can go about fixing that.

Comment: @SheelPatel please see edited answer and let me know if this handles these additional situations.